# Python restarts the shell when I tried to do math

Tags: python, shell, kernel, jupyter, ode

I have a problem with the following code. I tried a lot of web pages to find some solutions but I could not manage to.
The problem is when I run this script after just 4 lines of printing, Python restarts the shell. In `jupyter` it sends message: `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

I try to read a file at the first of the script containing (`300,000`) rows of data. then after calculating the `ODE` and other functions, I expect to print the results for comparison

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad  
import math
import pandas as pd

hr, dr, cr, br = np.genfromtxt('outputs/new.txt',unpack=True)

def OD_H(od, z, c, b):
   Omegai = (1-od)
   div1 = np.divide(1, (1 + z), where = (1 + z)!= 0)     
   dMdt = -(div1) * (2 *(1-od)* (-2 + (od/(6 * c))) + 3 - 3 * b**2 * Omegai - 3 * od)
return dMdt

def ant(H0, z, od0, c, b):
    z1 = 0
    od = odeint(OD_H, od0, [z1, z], args=(c, b))[-1]                   
    return od   

def dec(H0, z, od0, c, b):
    od = ant(H0, z, od0, c, b)
    q = -1 - (-2 + od/(6 * c))
    return q

for i in range(len(hr)):
    for z in range (0,1):
        print(dec(hr[i], z, dr[i], cr[i], br[i]),hr[i], dr[i], cr[i], br[i])
```

It is a simple code, but I do not know what the eventual problem is.
I really appreciate any help.

the input file (`new.txt`) could be

```
71.076588184266 0.40147988209522 0.080396967668756 0.050302016457046
71.02284157687 0.39756707964421 0.080918035449145 0.050501956013259
71.102923163306 0.41587392748136 0.07823452108922 0.049336707395359
70.860444589498 0.46748446539443 0.072392464271658 0.046667808684486
70.181278149341 0.44888833570037 0.077917371645449 0.04777288009128
70.588452406351 0.49035265611716 0.072303154996487 0.045942096884044
70.588452406351 0.49035265611716 0.072303154996487 0.045942096884044
70.011812869146 0.44210637315163 0.07871914246357 0.048393990901086
69.807956729005 0.41349634394633 0.082020266421564 0.049900569076028
69.807956729005 0.41349634394633 0.082020266421564 0.049900569076028
69.807956729005 0.41349634394633 0.082020266421564 0.049900569076028
70.123419349447 0.43961350279409 0.07862300319627 0.048607832896286
70.361666430312 0.41397677666087 0.080502527828865 0.049745843125116
70.361666430312 0.41397677666087 0.080502527828865 0.049745843125116
70.357430153315 0.41485946940097 0.08042642593323 0.049703105696664
70.357430153315 0.41485946940097 0.08042642593323 0.049703105696664
71.551080656041 0.51047305096688 0.066682530098241 0.0446474321235
```

Comment: create a different copy of new.txt with just 30 rows of data or something. if it loads, you can confirm what i suspect: that this is most probably you not having enough ram to hold all your data. Just a typical memory issue.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh yes I tried for some prior calculations having this problem, after adding 4 GB extra ddr3 RAM my problem was solved. But now I have 8 GB RAM. But let me now do your suggestion. Wait a min...

Comment: @ParitoshSingh  No, with a text file having 17 rows again I have the same problem

Comment: can you provide the smallest input that still allows replicating the problem?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh what do you mean, I could not catch it

Comment: You have your code here, but no input for us to use. can you provide us with something from your `new.txt` (but not the entire 300,000 rows). Try to see if the issue happens when you have only 2 or 3 rows in a separate file, and if it does, give us those lines.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I added the input data

Comment: Ok, just an update, this is not a memory problem, and nor is it a data problem. I can successfully recreate the problem on 5 iterations of the code. What is interesting is that i can recreate the problem by looping for the same result with the same inputs 5 times, and it will work like a charm first couple of times.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh well, you meant you have found the solution?

Comment: Im afraid not quite yet. i think i have a rough guess at the culprit though.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh  This interrupts and slows my speed. I need this and I have never ran in to such a problem so far

Comment: Is this just a test case or do you usually use numerical solvers to integrate over intervals of length zero? `z in range(0,1):` produces exactly one loop with `z=0`, and then the passed time interval is `[z1, z] = [0.0, 0.0]`.

Comment: @LutzL It was a test case. indeed it is `np.arange(0,0.8,0.001)`

Comment: If you test the original code with `np.arange(0,0.8,0.1)[1:]` you should get an error free run. Or test for `z==0` resp. `abs(z-z1)<1e-15` and just return the initial values without calling `odeint` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, So the issue is with `odeint`. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) recommend switching to [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) instead.

Now full disclaimer, i have absolutely zero idea what any of this means, the math and meanings of things were beyond me. However, i tried to best mimic odeint behaviour with solve_ivp, which out of the box does not accept args. Presenting, ghetto lambda to the rescue.

```
od = odeint(OD_H, od0, [z1, z], args=(c, b))[-1] #before
od = solve_ivp(lambda od, z: OD_H(od, z, c, b), t_span = [z1, z], y0 = [od0])['y'][-1][-1] #after
```

note that this is not QUITE a replacement, the result of solve ivp presents a float in this manner, and you'd want to wrap it as `[od]` instead to exactly match the old result.
As for the minimal code i used to narrow out odeint, you can see the battlefield below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
#from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad  
#import math
#import pandas as pd

hr, dr, cr, br = np.genfromtxt('new.txt',unpack=True)




def OD_H(od, z, c, b):
   Omegai = (1-od)
   div1 = np.divide(1, (1 + z), where = (1 + z)!= 0)     
   dMdt = -(div1) * (2 *(1-od)* (-2 + (od/(6 * c))) + 3 - 3 * b**2 * Omegai - 3 * od)
   return dMdt

def ant(H0, z, od0, c, b):
    z1 = 0
    #od = odeint(OD_H, od0, [z1, z], args=(c, b))[-1] #this solver crashed
    od = solve_ivp(lambda od, z: OD_H(od, z, c, b), t_span = [z1, z], y0 = [od0])['y'][-1][-1] #this worked out. perhaps wrap in square brackets [od] if needed.
    #od = OD_H(od0,z,c,b)  #this alone without the solvers worked fine              
    return od   

#def dec(H0, z, od0, c, b): #remove the middleman
#    od = ant(H0, z, od0, c, b)
#    q = -1 - (-2 + od/(6 * c))
#    return od

for i in range(5): #simple check instead
    z = 0 #you do not need a loop here
    res = ant(hr[i], z, dr[i], cr[i], br[i])
    print(res)
        #print(dec(hr[i], z, dr[i], cr[i], br[i]),hr[i], dr[i], cr[i], br[i]) print was not the culprit
```

Bottom line though, i do not quite know (yet) why odeint crashed this way.

**EDIT:**

For the op, here would be how the code would look updated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
#from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad  
#import math
#import pandas as pd

hr, dr, cr, br = np.genfromtxt('new.txt',unpack=True)

def OD_H(od, z, c, b):
   Omegai = (1-od)
   div1 = np.divide(1, (1 + z), where = (1 + z)!= 0)     
   dMdt = -(div1) * (2 *(1-od)* (-2 + (od/(6 * c))) + 3 - 3 * b**2 * Omegai - 3 * od)
   return dMdt

def ant(H0, z, od0, c, b):
    z1 = 0
    #od = odeint(OD_H, od0, [z1, z], args=(c, b))[-1]  
    od = [solve_ivp(lambda od, z: OD_H(od, z, c, b), t_span = [z1, z], y0 = [od0])['y'][-1][-1]]
    return od   

def dec(H0, z, od0, c, b):
    od = ant(H0, z, od0, c, b)
    q = -1 - (-2 + od/(6 * c))
    return q

for i in range(len(hr)):
    for z in range (0,1):
        print(dec(hr[i], z, dr[i], cr[i], br[i]),hr[i], dr[i], cr[i], br[i])
```

The output for the above data looks like this:

```
[0.16771346] 71.076588184266 0.40147988209522 0.080396967668756 0.050302016457046
[0.18113212] 71.02284157687 0.39756707964421 0.080918035449145 0.050501956013259
[0.11404428] 71.102923163306 0.41587392748136 0.07823452108922 0.049336707395359
[-0.07627332] 70.860444589498 0.46748446539443 0.072392464271658 0.046667808684486
[0.03981973] 70.181278149341 0.44888833570037 0.077917371645449 0.04777288009128
[-0.13031641] 70.588452406351 0.49035265611716 0.072303154996487 0.045942096884044
[-0.13031641] 70.588452406351 0.49035265611716 0.072303154996487 0.045942096884044
[0.06395836] 70.011812869146 0.44210637315163 0.07871914246357 0.048393990901086
[0.15976794] 69.807956729005 0.41349634394633 0.082020266421564 0.049900569076028
[0.15976794] 69.807956729005 0.41349634394633 0.082020266421564 0.049900569076028
[0.15976794] 69.807956729005 0.41349634394633 0.082020266421564 0.049900569076028
[0.06809821] 70.123419349447 0.43961350279409 0.07862300319627 0.048607832896286
[0.14293214] 70.361666430312 0.41397677666087 0.080502527828865 0.049745843125116
[0.14293214] 70.361666430312 0.41397677666087 0.080502527828865 0.049745843125116
[0.14029196] 70.357430153315 0.41485946940097 0.08042642593323 0.049703105696664
[0.14029196] 70.357430153315 0.41485946940097 0.08042642593323 0.049703105696664
[-0.27587903] 71.551080656041 0.51047305096688 0.066682530098241 0.0446474321235
```

The code i can use for comparison is this. Notice the old odeint solver but with only 4 values printed.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
#from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad  
#import math
#import pandas as pd

hr, dr, cr, br = np.genfromtxt('new.txt',unpack=True)

def OD_H(od, z, c, b):
   Omegai = (1-od)
   div1 = np.divide(1, (1 + z), where = (1 + z)!= 0)     
   dMdt = -(div1) * (2 *(1-od)* (-2 + (od/(6 * c))) + 3 - 3 * b**2 * Omegai - 3 * od)
   return dMdt

def ant(H0, z, od0, c, b):
    z1 = 0
    od = odeint(OD_H, od0, [z1, z], args=(c, b))[-1]  
    #od = [solve_ivp(lambda od, z: OD_H(od, z, c, b), t_span = [z1, z], y0 = [od0])['y'][-1][-1]]
    return od   

def dec(H0, z, od0, c, b):
    od = ant(H0, z, od0, c, b)
    q = -1 - (-2 + od/(6 * c))
    return q

for i in range(4): #simplified to avoid crash
    for z in range (0,1):
        print(dec(hr[i], z, dr[i], cr[i], br[i]),hr[i], dr[i], cr[i], br[i])
```

And the output:

```
[0.16771346] 71.076588184266 0.40147988209522 0.080396967668756 0.050302016457046
[0.18113212] 71.02284157687 0.39756707964421 0.080918035449145 0.050501956013259
[0.11404428] 71.102923163306 0.41587392748136 0.07823452108922 0.049336707395359
[-0.07627332] 70.860444589498 0.46748446539443 0.072392464271658 0.046667808684486
```

The code you provided does not always generative negative values. I do not presume to understand why you'd expect or want them to do so, but the results should match with the original code.

Comment: Before anything I have to ask one question. If you use `def dec()` function, the printed results are `positive` while  the whole of them must be negative. Ofcourse in this way I dont know the final answers. I mean they are wrong results

Comment: If the results are wrong, then they are a consequence of the code you gave. You would have to check the logic of the equations or so on. Check update, see if that gives you any clues. @MaY I am afraid i cannot help you with the logic behind the math of it all.

Comment: No, No, the code is correct, even in the previous code which 5 lines were printed we could see the negative values. But the answer of this code is positive entirely. This code is used in many prior works.

Comment: I have posted the answer of the new code. it has negative values too. So i am not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: You helped me a lot. Thank you so much

Comment: No worries, glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work as expected with one small change: Avoid a zero-length integration interval, if that is encountered, directly return the initial value.

```
def ant(H0, z, od0, c, b):
    z1 = 0
    if type(od0) is np.float64: od0 = np.array([od0]); # for uniform output
    od = od0 if abs(z-z1) < 1e-15 else odeint(OD_H, od0, [z1, z], args=(c, b))[-1]                   
    return od
```